# How to upload a video file to firebase storage using onCall cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to implement an `onCall` firebase cloud function that uploads uploads a local `.mp4` file to firebase storage. [The documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload) says that I can just simply pass in the local file path, however the cloud function error log mentions that no such file exists. I can guarantee that it does exist. What is the correct way of uploading an `.mp4` to a firebase cloud bucket?

index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.uploadVideo = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
    return bucket.upload(data.filePath,
        { destination: 'videos/test.mp4'}
    );
})
```

app.js

```
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/functions';
await firebase.functions()
                .httpsCallable('uploadVideo')({'filePath': videoFile})
```

cloud func log

```
Unhandled error [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../Documents/recording.mp4'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../Documents/recording.mp4'
}
```

Comment: You can't just pass a client machine file path to Cloud Functions.  It simply can't read the files on the client machine that invoked the function.  It can only read files that exist on its own backend filesystem, or through whatever product API you might be using.  You should instead just upload the file directly to the bucket using the Firebase SDK and deal with it from there somehow.

Comment: ok, so then I guess the local in this documentation https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload, local refers to the container the cloud function is in?